# Xamarin Forms Shell bind flyout icon theme aware

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I have a Xamarin Forms Shell Application with a flyout. My entries are defined like this:

```
<FlyoutItem Title="{x:Static resources:Strings.DashboardTitle}" FlyoutIcon="ic_dashboard_black">
    <Tab>
        <ShellContent>
            <dashboard:DashboardPage />
        </ShellContent>
    </Tab>
</FlyoutItem>
```

This works so far as the icons is shown. But to support light and dark theme I would like for example to be able to bind that with an AppThemeBinding. Is that possible? Or how would I theme the icons in the flyout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AppThemeBinding markup extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/system-theme-changes#appthemebinding-markup-extension) to define image source under light/dark mode:

```
<FlyoutItem Title="{x:Static resources:Strings.DashboardTitle}" FlyoutIcon="{AppThemeBinding Light=lightlogo.png, Dark=darklogo.png}">
    <Tab>
        <ShellContent>

        </ShellContent>
    </Tab>
</FlyoutItem>
```

The following requirements must be met for Xamarin.Forms to respond to a system theme change:

- Xamarin.Forms 4.6.0.967 or greater.
- iOS 13 or greater.
- Android 10 (API 29) or greater.
- UWP build 14393 or greater.

Responding to a system theme change is currently experimental, and can only be used by setting the `AppTheme_Experimental` flag.

Refer: [Enable flags in platform projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/internals/experimental-flags#enable-flags-in-platform-projects)